# issue with form method get on next page, would like for people to not see the initial page unless they hit the submit button

Tags: php

I have two PHP files.

The first is called "file1.php":

```
<form action="file2.php" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="price" value="50">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
<input type="submit" border="0" name="submit" value="Buy Now">
</form>
```

---

The second is called "file2.php":

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="text" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $_GET["price"]; ?>" readonly="readonly" />
</form>
```

---

Now here's my issue:

Some people may look at the source of the page on file1.php and try visiting file2.php. I would want them to be automatically redirected the file1.php or not be able to see file2.php UNLESS they have clicked the submit button from file1.php.

Also some people might try erasing the data was sent from the GET method from the previous page (file1.php), to be able to view file2.php, is there a way to block this from happening? I wouldn't want it to show a 404 error, but simply redirect the person to the file1.php page unless they click on one of the submit buttons from file1.php as there are many forms.

---

I believe this might have something to do with PHP require to be placed on file2.php, but not quite sure how to get it working properly.

Any ideas?

---

### *EDIT* (below)

Thank you everyone so far for all your help and advice.

Alright, so everything seems to be working now using the form method POST. However, to get this working, we must list all variables for each template. Each template has 4 variables. 2 IDs and 2 prices. In example:

```
$T900_0001_R_ID = "#900-0001 - Regular"; 
$T900_0001_R = 75; 
$T900_0001_E_ID = "#900-0001 - Exclusive"; 
$T900_0001_E = 500;
```

---

Now, my next question is: how do we convert this code to be used into a MySQL database instead, as there will be hundreds, and maybe thousands of templates to sold within just the next few weeks?

---

### See the updated files that are working (without MySQL):

file1.php:

```
<?php
$T900_0001_R_ID = "#900-0001 - Regular"; 
$T900_0001_R = 75; 
$T900_0001_E_ID = "#900-0001 - Exclusive"; 
$T900_0001_E = 500; 

echo "<form action='test2.php' method='post'><input type='hidden' name='template_price' value='" . $T900_0001_R . "'><input type='hidden' name='template_id' value='" . $T900_0001_R_ID . "'><input type='submit' class='buynow' border='0' name='submit' value='Buy Regular'></form>";
?>
```

file2.php:

```
<?php
$T900_0001_R_ID = "#900-0001 - Regular"; 
$T900_0001_R = 75; 
$T900_0001_E_ID = "#900-0001 - Exclusive"; 
$T900_0001_E = 500; 

echo "<form><input type='text' id='template_id' name='template_id' value='" . $_POST["template_id"] . "' alt='" . $_POST["template_price"] . "' readonly='readonly' class='input-text sum' /></form>";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

People might do a lot of things. They might take the values from file1.php and POST them. Or POST things to try to break your program.

The best thing you can do is validate your parameters to make sure they have the values you expect before you execute various commands.

In your example you could validate that price is a number:

```
if( isset($_POST['price'] ) && is_numeric($_POST['price'] ) ) {
     // process
}
else {
    //redirect to file1.php or show an error
}
```

However it does look like you're posting the price of an item through the form. If you're worried about someone viewing the source, why aren't you worried about someone changing the value of the price? It's a trivial thing to do. My code above wouldn't prevent it. You'd have to check to make sure the posted price is the actual price of the item, but if you're doing that why do you need to post it from the form in the first place?

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. So we're actually looking at getting the price from file1.php be shown into a readonly field on the file2.php as the customer checks out. This is where they go to review their order. The first, file1.php will have many different products to choose from, and once the customer chooses a product (click the submit-buy now button), they get redirected to the order confirmation page where they get to review their price and enter their shipping info. Any idea on how to secure this? The script uses the price in the input tag to calculate prices. That's why I can't remove it.

Comment: @Lucille - the only way to secure it is to change the script so that it gets the price internal to the program. As long as the price comes from the input, someone can change it.

Comment: Is there any way to encrypt data in the file1.php (before sending to the server), decrypt while reading at the server, and encrypt again when being sent via GET method at file2.php? At the beginning we can verify the prices and data, but in the future, it'd be nice if there would be an automatic way to encrypt/decrypt the data itself. I've found this from doing a quick search on Google, http://php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.examples.php, just not quite sure if it would work, or even where to start on implementing it.

Comment: You could certainly encrypt the data but that seems like extra work for little gain (and detrimental to performance). The quick fix is to store the price on the server in the database and look it up again, or even put it in the user's PHP session. So instead of $_POST['price'], use $_SESSION['price']

Comment: The $_SESSION doesn't seem to be working really. It keeps redirecting to page file1.php everytime I click the submit button. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

So check for submit (i would advise switching the method on file1.php to `post`)

In file2.php:

```
if(count($_POST)){ //0 is false, any other number true
   //do stuff
}
else {
   header('Location: file1.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make the first page a post, then on the second file check the post:

```
if(isset($_POST['id'] && $_POST['price']) {
    // Display second form
} else {
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the top of `file2.php`

```
<?php

if(!isset($_GET['id']) && !isset($_GET['price'])) {
    header('Location: file1.php');
    die();
}

?>
```

## On the edit

Except that I don't like questions to be edited in a very other direction, you have to first create a database table. It will look like

```
ID type price
 1    e   500
 1    r    75
 2    e   250
 2    r    50
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. This seems to be working. Would you have any idea on how to add further security in the code so that people CANNOT alter what's being posted in the address bar at on file2.php? As this will break all calculations from the script. I'm sure there's a way, just don't know where to start really.

Comment: @Lucille: IMHO you have to requery the price on the server side. I believe that the `id` and the `price` somehow relate to each other. So you have to query the price based on the id. That can be accomplished through various methods. If there are not many ids, use a array to look up the prices, else query a database, e.g. mysql.

Comment: How would I convert the following to MySQL query:
<?php
$T1_R_ID = "#1 - Regular"; 
$T1_R = 5; 
$T1_E_ID = "#1 - Exclusive"; 
$T1_E = 50; 
?>

Comment: Maybe you could paste some more code somewhere? I dont see what your code means.

Comment: It's a custom built shopping cart that we're working with. At the moment, selling templates. There are already 75, and will be many more added daily. Each template has 4 different PHP variables to reference.
1st: (ID of regular price),
2nd: (regular price shown),
3rd: (ID of exclusive price),
4th: (exclusive price shown)

Comment: I believe that your app has some serious issues. You should externalize the data away from the code into a database table, e.g. Pricelist with fields `id|type|price`, then you could just ask the user of the form whether he wants to buy regular or exclusive and send this data with the id. `SELECT price FROM Pricelist WHERE id = ? and type = ?` will pull it. But this is far beyond the scope of the question. Though if you provide more code, I will take a look.

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for the reply. I've edited the initial question at the top. So how would I convert the 4 PHP variables to MySQL?

Comment: Marc, thanks so much for all the help. MySQL db aside....I've come up with another issue. As mentionned in the EDITed note at the top, everything seems to working properly on my test files with form method POST and $_POST. However, as soon as I add these codes into my site files, the input on the second page is not reading the value at all. I have other PHP code all over the page. Could it be interfering? When I switch from POST to GET, the value is shown, but here we go again, the insecurity issues in the address bar.